# How to store a table to a void table

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
void fill_buffer(void *buffer)
{
    char cbuf[20]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,11,12,13,14,15};
    void* vbuf = (void*) cbuf;
    buffer=vbuf;
}
```

I am trying to fill the buffer that is given to me from the main function but I am not sure how to fill a void table properly. In the main function buffer is defined:

```
unsigned char buffer[20];
```

Comment: Why is the buffer passed as a void pointer? And you should know that simply assigning pointers does not copy the contents of the pointed-to objects

Comment: A pointer is not an array. And you are aware you don't copy `cbuf`, are you? What do you want to accomplish? And why do you use `void  *` at all? It is a last ressort for special usage; don't use it without true need.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? As it seems you need to copy to a buffer and not the other way around...

Comment: I am trying to get table cbuf transferred to table buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the data, because `cbuf` is local to `fill_buffer()` and it will be deallocated when the function returns, to do it try

```
void
fill_buffer(void *buffer, size_t bufsize)
{
    static const unsigned char cbuf = {
        1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7,  8, 
        9,  9,  9,  9, 9, 9, 9, 11,
       12, 13, 14, 15
    };
    if (bufsize > sizeof(cbuf) / sizeof(*cbuf))
        bufsize = sizeof(cbuf) / sizeof(*cbuf);        
    memcpy(buffer, cbuf, bufsize);
}
```

you should ensure, that the destination `buffer` has enough storage allocated, in this case `bufsize` bytes, but if the type of `cbuf`'s elements is different you might have to use `sizeof(element_type)`.

Also, perhaps you could return the number of bytes **actually** copied.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: If the types don't match, the code can invoke UB. Using `void *` is not a good idea in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach which lets `fill_buffer` create their own array, thus assuring all contents end up in the buffer, is this:

```
void fill_buffer(void **buffer) {
    static const unsigned char cbuf[4] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 0,
    };
    *buffer = (void*)cbuf;
}
```

You can use it in `main` like this:

```
void* buffer;
fill_buffer(&buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers by Dunno and Iharob Al Asimi are correct, but here is an explanation why your code does not work:

Your function takes a pointer as a parameter, which is copied from the one you passed in the argument. Therefore, modifying the pointer within the function will not change the one originally passed into the function.

```
void fill_buffer(void *buffer);
int main()
{
    void* ptr = (void*) NULL;
    fill_buffer(ptr);
    printf("%d", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints: 0

This is the reason that Dunno used a pointer to a pointer, in order to change the value of the original pointer.

Also, here is a modified version of your code that works (but is bad coding practice, use Dunno's or Iharob Al Asimi's solution):

```
void fill_buffer(void *buffer);
int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[20];
    fill_buffer(buffer);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void fill_buffer(void *buffer)
{
    unsigned char* buff = buffer;
    unsigned char cbuf[20]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,11,12,13,14,15};
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       buff[i] = cbuf[i];
    }
}
```